# Email phishing, understand mail header

Tags: email, phishing, scam

I try to understand phishing email received from an attacker:

```
Received: ....

Received: ....

Received-SPF: Pass (sender SPF authorized) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=; helo= envelope-from:attacker@infected_website.com;receiver=victim@legit_site.com

Received: from mout.gmx.com ( [])
     by  (Postfix) with ESMTPS id =
     for <victim@legit_site.com>; Mon, 10 Feb 2019 13:06:35 +0100 (CET)

Received: from [IP_SRC] ([IP_SRC]) by
     .... (via HTTP); Mon, 10 Feb 2019 13:06:33 +0100
```

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question in an attempt to remove personal information. The information is all still there in the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the headers shared , the IP sending mail form GMX console is 74.208.4.XX, this pool of IP address belong to ISP: 1&1 Internet Inc.

There have been recent [abuse(Spam) reports](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/74.208.255.134) from this pool of IPs. Might be the tenent of the IP 74.208.4.xx is using GMX to send you the mails.

Request you to report to [GMX](https://support.gmx.com/email/spam-and-viruses/spam.html) and the [ISP](https://www.abuseipdb.com/whois/74.208.255.134) regarding this abuse.

There is a strong possibility that the IP 74.208.4.xx is compromised.

Comment: It depends .If you need the reports dating back to 1.5 years. Please check in virustotal.com , otx.alienvault.com. These sites may have older reports.